# Using monadic functions with Data.Map (fx unionWith)

Tags: haskell, dictionary, monads

I would like to union two [Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) instances with a monadic function. This becomes a problem because of the [`unionWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3aunionWith) type signature:

```
unionWith :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> Map k a -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

I'm looking for a smart way to do this. Here is my naive implementation:

```
monadicUnionWith :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (a -> a -> m a) -> Map k a -> Map k a -> m (Map k a)
monadicUnionWith f mapA mapB = do
  let overlapping = toList $ intersectionWith (\a b -> (a,b)) mapA mapB
  mergedOverlapping <- liftM fromList $ mapM helper overlapping
  return $ union (union mergedOverlapping mapA) mapB
  where
    helper (k, (a,b)) = do
      c <- f a b
      return (k, c)
```

*Note that `union` is left biased*

Comment: Your code doesn’t look too bad ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if it is more efficient, but it is somewhat cooler (as it involves storing monadic values in the map):

```
monadicUnionWith :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (a -> a -> m a) -> Map k a -> Map k a -> m (Map k a)
monadicUnionWith f mapA mapB =
  Data.Traversable.sequence $ unionWith (\a b -> do {x <- a; y <- b; f x y}) (map return mapA) (map return mapB)
```

And if you want you can use

```
(\a b -> join (liftM2 f a b))
```

as the parameter to `unionWith`, or even

```
((join.).(liftM2 f))
```

Comment: Hmm, it probably is more efficient, as the tree structure of the map is not destroyed (as with `fromList` and `toList`).

Comment: Yes, that was why I called my own solution "stupid". It didn't keep the tree structure. I should have just looked up how `mapM` was implemented, but didn't think of that then.

Comment: It should be noted that the `map` function used here is from Data.Map, not Prelude.